# JAVA - How to bypass closed XML tag without open tag

Tags: java, arrays, xml, string, dom

I am reading the following XML file:

At some point I am finding tags that are closed but not opened like location and size. My logic is reading these tags into an array and at some point and failing with a

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
<deviceInfo>
    <device>TV2345</device>
    <deviceType>Television</deviceType>
    <location/>
    <size/>
</deviceInfo>
```

Here is my code reading it and trying to escape it, but it's not working:

```
Node nNode = nList.item(i);

if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
  Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

  String LocationNode=eElement.getElementsByTagName("location").item(0).getTextContent();

  if (LocationNode.length() > 0) {
    String DEVICEID = eElement.getElementsByTagName("deviceId").item(0).getTextContent();
    String[] LOCATION = eElement.getElementsByTagName("location").item(0).getTextContent().split("\\/");        
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `getElementsByTagName` method which returns `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` object. In case there is no elements with given name `NodeList.getLength` method returns `0`. So, below code safely gets text content:

```
NodeList locations = document.getElementsByTagName("location");
if (locations.getLength() > 0) {
    String textContent = locations.item(0).getTextContent();
    System.out.println(textContent);
}
```

Or you can create method which will does it:

```
public static String getFirstTextContent(Document node, String tagName) {
    NodeList locations = node.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    if (locations.getLength() > 0) {
        return locations.item(0).getTextContent();
    }

    return "";
}
```

and your code could look like this:

```
String locationNode = getFirstTextContent(document, "location");

if (locationNode.length() > 0) {
    String DEVICEID = getFirstTextContent(document, "deviceId");
    String[] LOCATION = getFirstTextContent(document, "location").split("\\/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In example xml:

```
<deviceInfo>
    <device>TV2345</device>
    <deviceType>Television</deviceType>
    <location />
    <size />
</deviceInfo>
```

There is no `deviceId` tag, but you're trying to get first item from `NodeList`:

```
eElement.getElementsByTagName("deviceId").item(0);
```

And this operation is failing with `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`